# Initialise pytorch convolution layer with my own values

Tags: pytorch, initialization, conv-neural-network, tensor

I want to know if there's a way to initialize pytorch convolution filter with my own values.

eg, I have a tuple `[-0.8423,  0.3778][-3.1070, -2.6518]` and I want to initialize a 2X2 filter with these values, how do I do that? I looked up some answers but they were mostly using torch normal distribution and others. Nothing that I can't specify.

Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly assign values to weigts:

```py
conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=2)
with torch.no_grad():
  conv.weight.data = torch.tensor([[-0.8423,  0.3778],[-3.1070, -2.6518]])  # you might need to play a bit with the dimensionality of this tensor
```

Comment: Why have you put torch.no_grad()? I want to use it for training. So is that necessary?

Comment: you need gradients from the loss,not the init

Comment: Oh. Makes sense.

Comment: So when we initialize these layers with random weights in the beginning in the usual case, then why don't we use no_grad()?

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta look at the torch.init code